# how to store a array of object in prisma (psql)

Tags: postgresql, prisma

hello i have this object

```
type starter = {
    name: string
    weight: number
}

type ToStore = {
    brand: string
    starter?: starter[]
}

const toStore: ToStore = {
    brand: "toto",
    starter: [
        {
            name:"auto",
            weight: 15.7
        },
        {
            name:"manual",
            weight: 13.7
        }
    ]
}
```

and im wondering how i do the model for this kind of data ?

thanks everyone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have found two solution 
jsonB or relational table, wat is the more performant ?

Comment: Hey @loan you should use a relation table. Json should be used when there is no structure to the data. If you have a more specific question, please update this post and I'll try to help.